# database polling using Java

Tags: java

I am stuck at some point wherein I need to get database changes in a Java code. Request is to get any record updated, added, deleted in any table of db; should be recognized by Java program. How could it be implemented JMS? or a Java thread?

**Update:** Thanks guys for your support i am actually using Oracle as DB and Weblogic 10.3 workshop. Actually I want to get the updates from a table in which I have only read permission so guys what do you all suggest. I can't update the DB. Only thing I can do is just read the DB and if there is any change in the table I have to get the information/notification that certain data rows has been added/deleted or updated.

Comment: Oracle's Change Data Capture, perhaps?

Comment: The Update is copypasted from the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363697/database-polling-using-java-closed

Comment: Only if you are working with an Oracle DB:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177723/how-to-call-java-class-from-oracle-trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177723/how-to-call-java-class-from-oracle-trigger)

Answer (score 8):

Unless the database can send a message to Java, you'll have to have a thread that polls.

A better, more efficient model would be one that fires events on changes.  A database that has Java running inside (e.g., Oracle) could do it.

Comment: What's an example of a product that fires events on changes?  I've never seen that.  Sounds like a database trigger but instead of running SQL (ie: PL/SQL), it runs a Java class that implements some interface.

Comment: Correct, and instead of writing your own threading system, use Java's Executors, which will make your life much simpler.

Answer (score 6):

We do it by polling the DB using an EJB timer task. In essence, we have a status filed which we update when we have processed that row.

So the EJB timer thread calls a procedure that grabs rows which are flagged "un-treated".

Dirty, but also very simple and robust. Especially, after a crash or something, it can still pick up from where it crashed without too much complexity.

The disadvantage is the wasted load on the DB, and also response time will be limited (probably requires seconds).

Answer (score 3):

We have accomplished this in our firm by adding triggers to database tables that call an executable to issue a Tib Rendezvous message, which is received by all interested Java applications.

However, the ideal way to do this IMHO is to be in complete control of all database writes at the application level, and to notify any interested parties at this point (via multi-cast, Tib, etc).  In reality this isn't always possible where you have a number of disparate systems.

Comment: +1 for "complete control of all database writes at the application level".  A service ought to own and control its own data.

Comment: The main point of a DBMS is to provide access to the data for multiple applications in a uniform way.  This includes applications that are as yet unthought of, much less implemented.  It precludes the possibility that a single application is in control of all the data.  Or, if you do produce a single application doing all the database operations, then you are using the 'real DBMS' as a storage engine and the 'single application' as the DBMS interface for all applications.  But it is close to redundant.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer - No, not necessarily.  The main point of a DBMS is persistence.  If future, unthought of applications need data, they can go through the owner to get it.  That's what services are all about.  That's the view taken by Werner Vogels, the CTO of Amazon: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1142065

Comment: @duffymo: Agreed.  Also, I've seen hybrid solutions whereby writers go through the "owning" service whereas readers have the option of querying the database directly.

Comment: Still couples them to the schema.  If it changes, their read has to change as well.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Lost cause. You know, they love to reinvent defective wheels.

Answer (score 2):

You're indeed dependent on whether the database in question supports it. You'll also need to take the overhead into account. Lot of inserts/updates also means a lot of notifications and your Java code has to handle them consistently, else it will bubble up.

If the datamodel allows it, just add an extra column which holds a timestamp which get updated on every insert/update. Most major DB's supports an auto-update of the column on every insert/update. I don't know which DB server you're using, so I'll give only a MySQL-targeted example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    somevalue VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lastupdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    INDEX (lastupdate)
)
```

This way you don't need to worry about inserting/updating the `lastupdate` yourself. You can just do an `INSERT INTO mytable (somevalue) VALUES (?)` or `UPDATE mytable SET somevalue = ? WHERE id = ?` and the DB will do the magic.

After ensuring that the DB server's time and Java application's time are the same, you can just fire a background thread (using either [`Timer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) with [`TimerTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html), or [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) with [`Runnable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)) which does roughly this:

```
Date now = new Date();
statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE lastupdate BETWEEN ? AND ?");
statement.setDate(1, this.lastTimeChecked);
statement.setDate(2, now);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    // Handle accordingly.
}
this.lastTimeChecked = now;
```

**Update**: as per the question update it turns out that you have no control over the DB. Well, then you don't have much good/efficient options. Either just refresh the entire list in Java memory with entire data from DB without checking/comparing for changes (probably the fastest way), or dynamically generate a SQL query based on the current data which excludes the current data from the results.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're talking about a situation where anything can update a table.  If for some reason you're instead talking about a situation where only the Java application will be updating the table that's different.  If you're using Java only you can put this code in your DAO or EJB doing the update (it's much cleaner than using a trigger in this case).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do this is to funnel all database calls through a web service API, or perhaps a JMS API, which does the actual database calls. Processes could register there to get a notification of a database update.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar requirement. In our case we have a legacy system that we do not want to adversely impact performance on the existing transaction table.

Here's my proposal:

1. A new work table with pk to transaction and insert timestamp
2. A new audit table that has same columns as transaction table + audit columns
3. Trigger on transaction table to dump all insert/update/deletes to an audit table
4. Java process to poll the work table, join to the audit table, publish the event in question and delete from the work table.

Question is: What do you use for polling? Is quartz overkill? How can you scale back the polling frequency based on the current DB load?