# How to call java class from oracle trigger?

Tags: java, oracle, triggers

I am use oracle 10g and jdk 1.6

I want to call java class from oracle Trigger for that I am tries below-

My java class is-

```
public class DBTrigger 
{
    public static void logSal()
    {
     System.out.println("In java class");
    }
}
```

and my oracle trigger is-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sal_trig
AFTER UPDATE OF sal ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.sal > 1.2 * old.sal)
CALL logSal();
```

but I am able to call it.

so please give me a suggestion.

Comment: Possibly, you can get your answers [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19503/error-calling-stored-procedure-from-trigger-in-oracle-database-11g)

Comment: But what location of java class.

Comment: Small comment. When usign Oracle 10g then if fact you're using Java 1.5 (on the DB serverver). Regardless of what JVM version you use your desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19503/error-calling-stored-procedure-from-trigger-in-oracle-database-11g) say is

1) create the Java class

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED My_JavaClass AS
import java.io.*;
public class DBTrigger 
{
    public static void logSal()
    {
     System.out.println("In java class");
    }
}
/
```

2) Create a stored procedure (a place holder basically) to call your java class

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE My_Javaclass_proc
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'DBTrigger.logSal()';
/
```

3) Create the trigger and call this procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sal_trig
AFTER UPDATE OF sal ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.sal > 1.2 * old.sal)
begin
  My_Javaclass_proc;
end;
/
```

Try to do using above steps and share the results.

Comment: Again I would say, follow the link, there the example is using parameters :)

Comment: I have already gone through this document but due to oracle XE i cant create a java class on sql develoeper.
@San can you guide if i have java class in local system then how can i call that class method

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the oracle docs [Calling Java from Database Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/04_call2.htm) ,You have to publish your Java method as procedure and have to call that procedure in the trigger.

Have a look at the example in the above link or [other example here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm#CACFGDCI)